# Is it possible to develop a flutter app with an internal database that uploads this data to an external database?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new with flutter and would like to know if it is possible to develop an app with an internal database that is checking the connection to the internet and when there is this connection the app will upload this data to an external database, a server in case?

For example, the app should function even offline but when on the internet perform a data synchronization with a server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do it by yourself (with backend) or with firebase which is pretty much more straightforward for a mobile dev

[Enabling Offline Capabilities](http://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

[Access data offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)